# Parse a non-ascii (unicode) number-string as integer in .NET

Tags: .net, unicode

I have a string containing a number in a non-ascii format e.g. unicode BENGALI DIGIT ONE (U+09E7) : `"১"`

How do I parse this as an integer in .NET?

Note: I've tried using `int.Parse()` specifying a bengali culture format with "bn-BD" as the IFormatProvider. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a new string that is the same as the old string except the native digits are replaced with Latin decimal digits. This could be done reliably by looping through the characters and checking the value of `char.IsDigit(char)`. If this function returns true, then convert it with `char.GetNumericValue(char).ToString()`.

Like this:

```
static class DigitHelper
{
    public static string ConvertNativeDigits(this string text)
    {
        if (text == null)
            return null;
        if (text.Length == 0)
            return string.Empty;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (char character in text)
        {
            if (char.IsDigit(character))
                sb.Append(char.GetNumericValue(character));
            else
                sb.Append(character);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}


int value = int.Parse(bengaliNumber.ConvertNativeDigits());
```

Comment: Don't forget that in many of these cultures they will be formatted Right-to-Left ;)

Comment: @ʞɔɐɯɹoↃɔW sǝɯɐſ - RTL should not be an issue, because Unicode defines the proper (logical) digit sequence to be most-significant to least-significant for all scripts. This is described in the Unicode Standard 6.0 in §2.5 (p.15).

Comment: Note that you will still want to use the correct culture to do the numeric conversion, since decimal, grouping, currency, and sign characters my differ.

Comment: Thanks for that, very interesting. I had no idea that in arabic script, they read words RtL but numbers LtR. Makes my brain ache! This article was also good: http://www.i18nguy.com/MiddleEastUI.html#answer

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this is [not possible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1c0s6bb.aspx) using built in functionality:

> The only Unicode digits that the .NET Framework parses as decimals are the ASCII digits 0 through 9, specified by the code values U+0030 through U+0039.
>
> ...
>
> The attempts to parse the Unicode code values for Fullwidth digits, Arabic-Indic digits, and **Bengali digits** fail and throw an exception.

(emphasis mine)

Very strange as `CultureInfo("bn-BD").NumberFormat.NativeDigits` does contain them.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that: one of the worst titled and most pointless articles on MSDN, right? Looks like a golden opportunity for someone to write a helper method and charge a meeelion dollars for it :D

Comment: @ʞɔɐɯɹoↃɔW sǝɯɐſ - Yeah. Though seeing as the array returned from `NativeDigits` is in the correct order (I think... don't read Bengali), a quick helper shouldn't be too difficult :)

Answer (score 0):

Having found this question while looking for a similar answer, but not finding any of the answers quite matched what I needed, I wrote the following as it treats signs okay, and is faster to fail if given a very long string. It does not though, ignore any grouping characters like `,`, `'`, `’`, though that could be easily added if someone wanted (I didn't):

```
public static int ParseIntInternational(this string str)
{
  int result = 0;
  bool neg = false;
  bool seekingSign = true; // Accept sign at beginning only.
  bool done = false; // Accept whitespace at beginning end or between sign and number.
                     // If we see whitespace once we've seen a number, we're "done" and
                     // further digits should fail.
  for(int i = 0; i != str.Length; ++i)
  {
    if(char.IsWhiteSpace(str, i))
    {
      if(!seekingSign)
        done = true;
    }
    else if(char.IsDigit(str, i))
    {
      if(done)
        throw new FormatException();
      seekingSign = false;
      result = checked(result * 10 + (int)char.GetNumericValue(str, i));
    }
    else if(seekingSign)
      switch(str[i])
      {
        case '﬩': case '+':
          //do nothing: Sign unchanged.
          break;
        case '-': case '−':
          neg = !neg;
          break;
        default:
          throw new FormatException();
      }
    else throw new FormatException();
  }
  if(seekingSign)
    throw new FormatException();
  return neg ? -result : result;
}
```