# C# char into int bigger than 256

Tags: c#, types

i need to convert some char to int value but bigger than 256. This is my function to convert int to char. I need reverse it

```
public static string chr(int number)
{
    return ((char)number).ToString();
}
```

This function doesnt work - its returning only 0-256, `ord(chr(i))==i`

```
public static int ord(string str)
{
    return Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str)[0];
}
```

Comment: Use a different encoding, maybe?

Comment: What coding? I tried utf-8 and ascii and its not working, i am making encrypting function to make bot and i was converting it from php, i practically need php ord function.

Comment: `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes` returns a byte array. A byte is unsigned: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693.aspx

Comment: Chr returns a single character concealed as a string. But in turn, GetBytes() returns an array of bytes. A byte in C# is from 0 upto 255. A byte is not a character. A character can span over many bytes in a string. Why didn't you just take a `string str` and take a first character from it?

Comment: Probably you should be using `int.Parse(str)` instead of `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str)[0]`

Comment: Maybe I am seeing it wrong, but if you only return the first position of the array of bytes, the value will always be between 0 and 255...

Comment: I need string str as int value. so for example "2" is chr(50) and i need make from "2" 50

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141255/parse-a-non-ascii-unicode-number-string-as-integer-in-net) looks like an answer.

Comment: `int i = (int)'ğ';` would give 287.  `char c = (char)287;` is the reverse op.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `ord` function truncates the character of the string to the first byte, as interpreted by UNICODE encoding. This expression

```
Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str)[0]
//                            ^^^
```

returns the initial element of a `byte` array, so it is bound to stay within the 0..255 range.

You can fix your `ord` method as follows:

```
public static int Ord(string str) {
    var bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str);
    return BitConverter.ToChar(bytes, 0);
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/jNXZfq)

Comment: Why did you use an encoding? Wouldn't a simple integer cast be enough?

Comment: @usr No, not without loss of generality. It appears that OP would like to make something encoding-dependent - perhaps he plans to pass different encodings to his `Ord` in a separate parameter. I cannot guess his intentions, so I kept as much of his code as I could.

Comment: @usr Perhaps you're right, but I think it's better to give new OPs a benefit of the doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't care much about encodings and you directly cast an `int` to a `char` in your `chr()` function, then why dont you simply try the other way around?

```
    Console.WriteLine((int)'\x1033');
    Console.WriteLine((char)(int)("\x1033"[0]) == '\x1033');
    Console.WriteLine(((char)0x1033) == '\x1033');
```

Answer (score 0):

char is 2 bytes long (UTF-16 encoding) in C#

```
char c1; // TODO initialize me
int i = System.Convert.ToInt32(c1); // could be greater than 255
char c2 = System.Convert.ToChar(i); // c2 == c1
```

System.Convert on MSDN : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Characters and bytes are not the same thing in C#.  The conversion between char and int is a simple one: (char)intValue or (int)myString[x].